# Does Godel's incompleteness theorems restricts the scope of connectionist-AI?

Tags: multilayer-perceptrons, symbolic-ai, universal-approximation-theorems, incompleteness-theorems

It is [well-known](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/3213/18758) that Godel's incompleteness theorems restricted the reachability of symbolic-AI, which is dependent on mathematical logic.

But, I am wondering whether it has any impact on the connectionist AI.

I don't think it has any impact on the capability of connectionist AI because of the following reasons I am aware of

1. [Connectionist-AI is more focused on generalization and is not about mathematical logic.](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/32758/18758).
2. Universal approximation theorem, contrary to Godel's incompleteness theorems says that connectionist-AI is capable of achieving all bounded-continuous functions. I am not sure about the implications of Godel's incompleteness theorems on either unbounded or discrete functions.

So, the incompleteness theorems *seem* to have no impact on the connectionist AI.

Do the theorems also restrict the reachability of connectionist-AI?